# Page FPS Drop and Functions

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, frame-rate

I wrote some JS code that rendering DOM (It is my custom carousel). My carousel has 2 buttons and they have some functions. When I trigger these functions in repeatedly, the DOM has difficulty in rendering. So the FPS of the page dropping slowly -half fps per second but very fast at beginning: 2-3 fps per second-.

You can see at right top (writes ortalama 2.68 fps):
https://ibb.co/8YvyJwn

And my performace json file:
https://gofile.io/?c=LIHiLh

```
const hizmetler = [{/* some datas */}];
    var index = 0;
    var slaytCount = hizmetler.length;

    showSlide(index);




    function showSlide(i) {
        index = i;

        if (i < 0) {
            index = slaytCount - 1;
        }
        if (i >= slaytCount) {
            index = 0;
        }

        const baslik = document.querySelector(".carousel-baslik");
        const metin = document.querySelector(".carousel-metin");
        const image = document.querySelector(".carousel-lg-image");
        const iconGround = document.querySelector(".icon-ground");
        const counter = document.querySelector(".counter");
        let iconImg = `<img src="${hizmetler[index].icon}" class="animated fadeInDown fast" alt="">`;
        let lgImage = `<img src="${hizmetler[index].lgImage}" class="animated fadeIn fast" alt="">`;

        baslik.innerHTML = hizmetler[index].baslik;
        metin.innerHTML = hizmetler[index].metin;
        image.innerHTML = lgImage;
        counter.innerText = hizmetler[index].count;
        iconGround.innerHTML = iconImg;

        document.querySelector('.controller-left').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            index--;
            showSlide(index);
            iconImg = `<img src="${hizmetler[index].icon}" class="animated fadeInLeft faster" alt="">`;
            document.querySelector(".icon-ground").innerHTML = iconImg;

        });

        document.querySelector('.controller-right').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            index++;
            showSlide(index);
            iconImg = `<img src="${hizmetler[index].icon}" class="animated fadeInRight faster" alt="">`;
            document.querySelector(".icon-ground").innerHTML = iconImg;
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please can you add all the relevant code _inside the question itself_? See [mcve] for more info.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I added now you can examine.

Answer (score 0):

I found to solution. When you run the click functions inside the showSlide function, something like an overload occurs and the page's FPS crashes. When I run the click functions independently, it does not cause any crash. \m/_